# Replacing a string occurance in panda with other string in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe (mapping) like this :

```
id  category
...............    
19  All Students    
20  Alter0tive Medicine 
21  A0lytics    
22  Enterprise 2.0
...................
..................
```

It have lot more rows. As you can notice in category column there is pattern of typo mistakes like in "A0lytics", and mistake is that "0" need to be replaced by "na" in almost all the case except 1 case where Enterprise 2.0 is correct. Exterprise 2.0 is the only exception in my whole datasets. How can I fix this issue. I tried various ways using using replace methods but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex. #Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"category":["All Students", "Alter0tive Medicine", "A0lytics", "Enterprise 2.0"]})
df["category"] = df["category"].str.replace(r"(?<=\w)0(?=\w)", "na")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
               category
0          All Students
1  Alternative Medicine
2             Analytics
3        Enterprise 2.0
```